# Error using function list in dcast.data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to reshape data using `dcast.data.table`, but, when I use predefined function list, `dcast.data.table` throws error.

```
require(data.table)
require(Hmisc)

n <- 2 
contributors <- 1:2
dates <- 2

DT <- data.table(ID = rep(rep(1:n, contributors), each = dates))
DT[, contributor := c(1,1,2,2,2,3)]
DT[, date := c(1,2,1,1,2,2)]
DT[, amount := rnorm(.N)]
DT[, rate := c(1,1,1,3,3,4)]
DT
#    ID contributor date     amount rate
# 1:  1           1    1 -1.3888607    1
# 2:  1           1    2 -0.2787888    1
# 3:  2           2    1 -0.1333213    1
# 4:  2           2    1  0.6359504    3
# 5:  2           2    2 -0.2842529    3
# 6:  2           3    2 -2.6564554    4

var.list <- as.list(Cs(amount, rate))

collapse <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = ',')
fun.list <- list(sum, collapse)

dcast.data.table(data = DT, ID + contributor ~ date,
                 fun.aggregate = fun.list,
                 value.var = var.list, fill = NA)
# Error in aggregate_funs(fun.call, lvals, sep, ...) : 
#   When 'fun.aggregate' and 'value.var' are both lists, 'value.var' must be either of length =1 or =length(fun.aggregate).
```

But the lengths are equal:

```
length(var.list) == length(fun.list)
# [1] TRUE
```

When `fun.aggregate` is defined directly in `dcast`, then there isn't any  problems:

```
dcast.data.table(data = DT, ID + contributor ~ date,
                 fun.aggregate = list(sum, collapse),
                 value.var = var.list, fill = NA)

#    ID contributor amount_sum_1 amount_sum_2 rate_collapse_1 rate_collapse_2
# 1:  1           1   -1.3888607   -0.2787888               1               1
# 2:  2           2    0.5026291   -0.2842529             1,3               3
# 3:  2           3           NA   -2.6564554              NA               4
```

I would like to know why this is happening and how could I bypass this error, to use predefined function list in `dcast.data.table`.

Comment: Looks like it is reported [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1369)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can build the call to `dcast` by hand, using `substitute()` to pass the user provided list literal to `dcast`, like so:

```
z = as.data.table(expand.grid(a=LETTERS[1:3],b=1:3,c=5:6,d=3:4,stringsAsFactors =FALSE))[sample(36,9)]

myfun = function(DT,fmla,funs,vars)
    do.call("dcast",list(zz,a~.,fun=substitute(funs),value.var = list('c','d')))

myfun(z,a~.,list(sum,mean),list('c','d'))

>     a c_sum   d_mean
>  1: A    24 3.500000
>  2: B    10 3.500000
>  3: C    18 3.333333
```

However, *your* user (i.e. whoever calls `myfun()` in this example) will have to provide a list literal, as this doesn't get around the internals of `dcast` which walk the AST of the argument passed to `fun.aggregate` which expects a list literal.